# QEMU fpu mode error when attempting to run MIPS binary

Tags: firmware, qemu, emulation

I have unpacked a firmware binary using binwalk and have identified the architecture as MIPS by running *file bin/busybox* . When I try to run the binary with the proper static version of qemu, i get an error with FPU mode ex:

```
 chroot . ./qemu-mips-static bin/busybox
 qemu: Unexpected FPU mode
```

I can't find anything on this error.  I have tried this on several different firmwares and i keep getting the same error.

The OS is Kali linux with qemu-user-static installed and the qemu-mips-static static binary place in the root directory of the unpacked firmware.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/0266c739abbed804deabb4ccde2aa449466ac3b4/linux-user/mips/cpu_loop.c#L703), the EABI from your ELF is not compatible. It seems to be specific to MIPS, you can find the structure [here](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/b98a66201dbc7cf3b962f4bb260f66100cc75578/include/elf.h#L101), this structure is stored inside a specific ELF segment, the code in charge to read it is [here](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/c4e0780ed1ffd056f205348d387a61b4136a45df/linux-user/elfload.c#L2431). I suggest you to make sure this segment is present and if it contains correct values. I think you can dump this information with `readelf(1)`.

Comment: How do I indentify the proper segment in readelf? what am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug of qemu. I had a similar issue and managed to resolve it by recompiling qemu with the patch suggested in [qemu mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/qemu-devel@nongnu.org/msg611477.html)